# Gradle - OutOfMemoryError when running tests, despite a ton of memory

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We have a multi-subproject Kotlin build - we're trying to migrate it from maven to gradle. The maven version of it builds fine, and can run all tests.

Gradle keeps running out of memory when running tests on our Jenkins server, in particular integration tests that involve scrypt functions. Again, these tests work fine when run under maven.

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16g -Xms2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
org.gradle.workers.max=1
```

gradlew:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xmx16g" "-Xms4g"'
```

build.gradle.kts: (root)

```
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict", "-XXLanguage:-NewInference")
```

buildSrc/Helpers.kt:

```
create<Test>("unit-tests") {
        useJUnit()
        useJUnitPlatform()
        maxParallelForks = 4
        maxHeapSize = "4G"
        reports.junitXml.isEnabled = true
        filter {
            setExcludePatterns(*TestPatterns.daoTests)
            isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
        }
        // prevents unit tests from subprojects from running in parallel (when gradle is run in parallel mode). we're
        // already using junit parallelism.
        // https://discuss.gradle.org/t/disabling-parallel-for-certain-tasks-only/10151
        outputs.files("/tmp/unit_test_lock")
    }

    create<Test>("int-tests") {
        useJUnit()
        useJUnitPlatform()
        maxParallelForks = 1
        setForkEvery(1)
        maxHeapSize = "16G"
        reports.junitXml.isEnabled = true
        filter {
            setIncludePatterns(*TestPatterns.daoTests)
            isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
        }
        // prevents int tests from subprojects from running in parallel (when gradle is run in parallel mode)
        // https://discuss.gradle.org/t/disabling-parallel-for-certain-tasks-only/10151
        outputs.files("/tmp/int_test_lock")
    }
```

What can I do to get the builds to go through?

Answer (score 0):

you are most likely exhausting the memory on the machine where the build is running - because you are setting 16 GB for both gradle and the test tasks.

remove the 16GB allocation (or revert to original size) for.
`gradle.properties` - `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16g -Xms2g` and
`gadlew` - `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xmx16g" "-Xms4g"'`

the create should take care of tests JVM.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I have 32GB of swap, at 16GB of RAM. It doesn't even top out the 16GB.

Comment: were you able to test removing the 2 entries ?

Comment: Yes. I've been testing combinations for literally a week. I started without those two entries.

Comment: It will run up to around 15GB used total (with a baseline usage of 4GB, so 11GB used total, and then bombs.) When I run the maven build, it tops out at 10GB (so 6GB used total.)